# Horizontal recyclerview in DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, drawerlayout

in drawer layout at the top I want horizontal list. There is no problem with scroll inside until I add onClick to viewHolder. Then recyclerview work only when scroll from left to right. To scroll from left to right I have to put finger in recyclerview move to the right and then I can scroll to left. If I start scrolling to left drawer will close. How can I disable scoll listener for drawer in this particular view?

My main layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:elevation="5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="304dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/drawerVerticalList"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and part of recyclerview adapeter

```
 @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = layoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(resourceId, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(view, new ViewHolder.ViewHolderClicks() {
            @Override
            public void onRVItemClick(String title, int ID) {
                //...
            }
        });
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.title.setText(...);

    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView title;
        public ViewHolderClicks mListener;
        public int ID;

        public ViewHolder(View viewItem, ViewHolderClicks mListener) {
            super(viewItem);
            title = (TextView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.title);
            this.mListener = mListener;
            viewItem.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.onRVItemClick(title.getText().toString(), ID);
        }

        public static interface ViewHolderClicks {
            public void onRVItemClick(String title, int ID);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I did try to set addOnScrollListener to recycleview and depend on state setDrawerLockMode but looks like 'drawer listener' has higher priority so this try fail.

Comment: I did find sample which helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32134373/horiziontal-recyclerview-on-drawerlayout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horiziontal recyclerview on DrawerLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32134373/horiziontal-recyclerview-on-drawerlayout)